# R DataTable Summarize Changes

Tags: r, tabs, data.table

```
library(data.table)

HAVE = data.table(STUDENT=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4),
TIME=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5),
SCORE=c(1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1))

WANT = data.table(TIMES=c(12,23,34,45),
SCORE00=c(0,1,0,0),
SCORE01=c(0,2,1,0),
SCORE10=c(3,1,0,0),
SCORE11=c(1,0,2,1))
```

I have data.table 'HAVE' which shows repeated STUDENT SCOREs over TIME. For each Time switch (1-2, 2-3, 3-4, 4-5) I wish to count the number of STUDENTs that change from 0-0, 0-1, 1-0, 1-1 as shown in 'WANT'.

Answer (score 2):

a `data.table` approach

```
# Set keys
setkey(HAVE, STUDENT, TIME)
HAVE[, `:=`(SCORE2 = paste0(shift(SCORE, type = "lag"), SCORE),
            TIMES  = paste0(shift(TIME, type = "lag"), TIME)),
     by = .(STUDENT)]
dcast(HAVE[!grepl("NA", SCORE2), ], TIMES ~ paste0("SCORE", SCORE2), fill = 0, 
      value.var = "TIMES", fun.aggregate = length)

#    TIMES SCORE00 SCORE01 SCORE10 SCORE11
# 1:    12       0       0       3       1
# 2:    23       1       2       1       0
# 3:    34       0       1       0       2
# 4:    45       0       0       0       1
```

Comment: is this cleanest way to do it ?

Comment: maybe there is a function we can make to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Surely not the tidiest solution:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

WANT <- HAVE %>% 
  split(.$STUDENT) %>% 
  map(~map2_chr(
    head(.x$SCORE, -1), tail(.x$SCORE, -1), str_c)
  ) %>% 
  data.table::transpose() %>% 
  map(~as_tibble(as.list(table(.x)))) %>% 
  map(~setNames(.x, str_c("SCORE", names(.x)))) %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  select(sort(names(.)))

WANT[is.na(WANT)] <- 0

WANT$TIMES <- unique(HAVE$TIME) %>%
  sort() %>%
  {map2_chr(head(., -1), tail(., -1), str_c)}

WANT <- WANT %>% select(TIMES, everything())
```

Answer (score 0):

Another basic and pipe-based alternative

```
WANTED <- split.data.frame(HAVE, HAVE$STUDENT) %>% 
                lapply(., function(x) {x$Score2 <- c(x$SCORE[2:nrow(x)], NA);  return(x)}) %>% 
                       rbindlist %>% 
                           .[complete.cases(.), ] %>% 
                                unite("ZF", SCORE, Score2, sep = ",") %>% 
                                     select(-STUDENT) %>% 
                                            table
```

with output

```
> split.data.frame(HAVE, HAVE$STUDENT) %>% 
+      lapply(., function(x) {x$Score2 <- c(x$SCORE[2:nrow(x)], NA);  return(x)}) %>% 
+            rbindlist %>% 
+              .[complete.cases(.), ] %>% 
+                unite("ZF", SCORE, Score2, sep = ",") %>% 
+                select(-STUDENT) %>% 
+                   table
    ZF
TIME 0,0 0,1 1,0 1,1
   1   0   0   3   1
   2   1   2   1   0
   3   0   1   0   2
   4   0   0   0   1
```